# Missing secret_token and secret_key_base for production environment, set these values in config/secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I get this error

> Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production'
>   environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`

And I added my `.yml` files to `.gitignore`.

I deployed to heroku

Comment: What host are you deploying to?

Comment: @mysmallidea heroku

Comment: and why you downvote? I thought it is considered a bad practice to commit yml files

Comment: It's ok to commit .yml files, as long as they don't contain any secret values. For Heroku, set your secret values using config vars: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: I don't know why they downvoted you, but maybe because your question could have been more detailed? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should commit your secret.yml file to your repository, but do not include your production key. Instead, set your production key from an environment variable, like this:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: xxxx

test:
  secret_key_base: yyyy

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Then generate a new secret key and set your ENV variable for Heroku like this:

```
$ rails secret
d3039b9b62a7311...
$ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE="d3039b9b62a7311..."
```

Or if you're into one-liners:

```
$ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=`rails secret`
```